# SharePoint list hidden folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have created a folder in sharepoint list using jsom but it is not visible, but when I hit the url of the folder, I am able to see an item which I created using code.

Below is the code:-

```
var clientContext;  
    var oWebsite;  
    var oList;  
    var itemCreateInfo;  
    var resultpanel="/sites/Dev/";  

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("EFMS_Location_Ref");  

    itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
    itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);  
    itemCreateInfo.set_leafName("rootFolderName");  
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    this.oListItem.set_item('Title', "rootFolderName");  
    this.oListItem.update();  

    clientContext.load(this.oListItem);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),  
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)  
    );  

    function successHandler() {  
           }  

    function errorHandler() {  
        resultpanel.innerHTML =  
            "Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message();  
    }
```

What is the issue, why this folder got hidden, how can I delete this hidden folder.
Also the next time when I run the same code, it created a new folder which is visible.
Now I want to delete the hidden folder that I have created..

Comment: If you only want to get rid of the hidden ones and that's it, you'll probably be able to see them when you navigate to the parent library in an Explorer View. In Explorer View, you can show the hidden items if they are not already visible.

Comment: I have already checked this, I think we dont have explorer view for list items

Comment: Can you check under your list's advanced settings that the 'Make "New Folder" command available" is enabled? Programmatically creating a folder could override this setting but then again restrain some functionality.